# How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY for multiple records creating a new record for each if not existing

Tags: mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key

I am using an `INSERT INTO` statement to create a record.
and when a `DUPLICATE KEY` error exists, I use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement to create a new records with a different number.

Example (assuming duplicate key is only on the name):

```
`table1` 
(name, id, timestamp) 
John, 300, 16:30 
Patrick, 400, 17:20

`table2` 
(name, id, timestamp)
John, 300, 18:00
Patrick, 400, 5:00
John, 300, 4:00
John, 300, 3:00
John, ...

INSERT INTO `table1` (name, id, timestamp)
SELECT `table2`.`name`, `table2`.id`, unix_timestamp()
FROM `table2`
WHERE `name` = "John"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table2`.id`+1
```

So far so good. In `table1` a new record is created; `John, 301, 18:00`.

But when `table2` has more than one `John`s, it **only** `UPDATE` (`INSERT`) the first `John` and then it ends.

I want that the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` keeps trying with a new id, because 301 does exist already, with maximum tries of 5 times.

The next record should look if a record with `John 300` already exists. If so, check 301, if so check 302, repeat till 306 and `INSERT` the first opportunity.

Comment: To me it seems you either want a simple auto_increment or a group-wise auto_increment.

Comment: You missing backticks before `id`.

Comment: You can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to create a new record. You use it to update the record in place that you're duplicating.

Comment: @Shadow Note that auto increment of secondary keys is only available in MyISAM, not InnoDB.

Comment: @Barmar I know. I'm trying to confirm what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join between the two tables to create a new ID.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, id, timestamp)
SELECT t2.name, IF(t1.maxid IS NULL, t2.id, t1.maxid + 1), unix_timestamp()
FROM table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name) AS t1 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.maxid IS NULL OR t1.maxid < t2.id + 5
```